# Large Data Table with first column fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have structure as shown in the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5LN7U/.

```
 <section class="container">
    <section class="field">
        <ul>
            <li> Question 1  </li>
            <li> question 2 </li>
            <li> question 3 </li>
            <li> question 4 </li>
            <li> question 5 </li>
            <li> question 6 </li>
            <li> question 7 </li>
        </ul>

    </section>
    <section class="datawrap">
        <section class="datawrapinner">
            <ul>
                <li><b>Answer 1 :</b></li>
                <li><b>Answer 2 :</b></li>
                <li><b>Answer 3 :</b></li>
                <li><b>Answer 4 :</b></li>
                <li><b>Answer 5 :</b></li>
                <li><b>Answer 6 :</b></li>
                <li><b>Answer 7 :</b></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </section>

</section>
```

Basically its a table structure made using divs. The first column contains a long list of questions and the second column contains answers/multiple answers which can be quite big (there has to be horizontal scrolling in the second column).

The problem I am facing is when I scroll downwards the second column which has the horizontal scroll bar is also scrolling downward. I want horizontal scrollbar to be fixed there. As in it should be always fixed there no matter how much I scroll vertically.

Much like Google Spreadsheets: where the first column stays fixed and there's horizontal scrolling on rest of the columns with overall vertical scrolling for whole of the data.

I cannot used position fixed in the second column.

P.S: I have my reasons for not using divs for making a table structure.

Comment: I dont get You i think, isnt that what You want?
http://jsfiddle.net/5LN7U/2/

Comment: @entio...do you see a horizontal scroll bar fixed at the bottom of the window. As in its always visible there no matter how much i scroll vertically.

Comment: i don' get it either, how answer and question are even related to each other within the markup ?  Multiple answer ? do you mean one ul for each question in li ?

Comment: So, maybe You just set overflow scroll on body and dont bother wrapping content in scrollable components?

Comment: I am sorry. I know its bit confusing. May be I am not putting it right words. But if you see any google spread sheets you'll see exactly what i am trying to achieve. i.e First column is fixed and rest of the columns are horizontally scrollable. @entio can you jot down a fiddle for your last comment.??

Comment: @GCyrillus.. Please don't bother about how they are related. consider it as two table cell (td's) in a table row. First table cell contains the question and second table cell contains the answers!!

Comment: @bhavya_w Did the `overflow-y:auto;` work for you?

Comment: @Fabian Mebus Overflow-y made the inner container( answers one ) scroll but i wanted both question and answers container to scroll. Nevermind i solved it using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If that is what you trying to achieve:

[image: Image with horizontal and vertical scrollbar]

You just have to set the `overflow-y:hidden;` in your **.datawrap** CSS class to `overflow-y:auto;`.